# Função javascript fazendo nodemon executar em loop

Tags: json, node.js, fs

Eu fiz uma função que funciona quando executada a partir de `node app.js`, mas quando executo com o Nodemon ele inicia e reinicia pra sempre.

A função em questão é usada pra escrever um JSON em um arquivo. Eu preciso usar o Nodemon porque otimiza muito meu tempo.

**Detalhe:** quando uso outro formato de arquivo, `.txt` por exemplo, ele funciona normalmente, mas preciso que o arquivo seja no formato `.json` porque vou armazenar as informações do baco de dados nele.

Minha função:

```
async function grava_login(){                          
 fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify({name: "Mohamed Almaci"}),
 "utf8", async function grava_login(err){
  try{                                                       
   if(err){                                                
    console.log(err);                                     
   }                                                      
   else{                                                   
    console.log("The file was saved!");                  
   }                                                     
 }                                                      
 catch{                                                  
  console.log("Erro ao salvar dados no arquivo json!")  
 }                                                     
})}                                                    
grava_login()
```

Comment: Ele deve ficar "reiniciando para sempre" porque o seu script escreve sempre um novo arquivo em uma pasta que provavelmente é observada pelo _listener_ do Nodemon...

Comment: Tentei mudar mais não funcionou, mas o estranho é que em outros formatos de arquivo funciona :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação da biblioteca Nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon), caso nenhuma configuração seja fornecida para a biblioteca ela irá observar os seguintes tipos de arquivo: `.js`, `.mjs`, `.coffee`, `.litcoffee`, e `.json`.

Isso significa que o processo do Nodemon irá verificar quaisquer alterações feitas em arquivos com essas extensões. Quando um desses arquivos mudar, ele reincia o processo.

#### O que está acontecendo com o seu código

A função `grava_login` irá escrever no arquivo `data.json`, dentro do diretório raiz o conteúdo `{"name": "Mohamed Almaci"}`.

Quando isso acontecer o processo do Nodemon irá entender que um arquivo com extensão `.json` foi modificado e irá reiniciar a sua aplicação. Quando a aplicação reiniciar, ela irá chamar a função `grava_login`. Criando assim um ciclo infinito de execuções da sua aplicação.

#### Como resolver o problema

A [documentação](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#nodemon) informa que é possível criar um [arquivo de configuração](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files) do Nodemon. Para isso, basta criar um arquivo com o nome `nodemon.json` na raiz do seu projeto. Com ele, é possível especificar os tipos de arquivos e diretórios a serem "observados".
No seu caso, incluir nesse arquivo a propriedade: `"ignore": ["*.json"]` deve resolver o problema.

**Exemplo de como deve ficar o seu arquivo `nodemon.json`**

```js
{
  "ignore": ["*.json"]
}
```

Comment: Boa garoto, sabia que o que estava acontecendo mas não sabia que ia ter que criar um arquivo de configuração json. Imaginei que ia ter que ler a documentação (que geralmente é grande aí postei no Stack overflow), a mensagem estava na minha cara quando iniciava o nodemon na verdade kkk, a mensagem que estava exibindo quando executava o nodemon:

Comment: [nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json

Comment: Foi falta de atenção minha, obrigado

Answer (score -2):

No meu caso esse loop acontecia tanto com o nodemon quanto com os plugins 'Live Server' e 'Five Server' do VSCode/VSCodium. E descobri que isso acontecia simplesmente porque estava a executar o meu código dentro da pasta da minha Cloud.

Cheguei a essa conclusão graças a esta outra resposta:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013459